# find, replace and discard values in dataframe in R

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to find, replace and discard values in dataframe in R. I'm using the built in Loblolly data set in R. I want to replace the height data recorded during the growth of seed 311 with NAs; and then discard all data from three-year-old trees.

I tried this, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
for('311' in Loblolly$Seed) Loblolly$height <- 'NA'
```

In Matlab there is a nice find function, are there any analogs in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ifelse()` function for this task.

```
data(Loblolly)
Loblolly$height <- ifelse(Loblolly$Seed == 311, NA, Loblolly$height)
```

The above replaced height with NA for only Seed 311.

To make a new data frame excluding the 3 year old trees you can do:

```
Loblolly2 <- Loblolly[Loblolly$age != 3, ]
```

Below I print just rows 20-30 to show the results for Seed 311:

```
Loblolly2[20:30, ]
   height age Seed
74  59.07  25  307
19  11.20   5  309
33  28.66  10  309
47  41.66  15  309
61  53.31  20  309
75  63.05  25  309
20     NA   5  311
34     NA  10  311
48     NA  15  311
62     NA  20  311
76     NA  25  311
```